# Join strings from a List<string> while also formating them

Tags: c#, strings, ldap

The code I have wrote works fine, this inquiry being purely for educational purposes. I want to know how others would do this better and cleaner. I especially hate the way I add the list items to another list before they are joined. There has to be a more efficient way.

I realize an easy way to make this simple would be to store "OU=" and "DC=" in the database with their associated text, but that just feels unseemly to me.

I am building a string for the container argument of the `PrincipalContext` class for an LDAP call.

The "lst" `List<string>` contains `DataRows` of LDAP Organization Units like "Accounts", "Users", etc.

```
// Get ou list
List<string> lst = db.sda(sql).Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("txt")).ToList();

string OU = string.Empty;
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

foreach (string ou in Web.Info.Ldap.ouList)
{
    lst.Add(string.Format("OU={0}", ou));
}
OU = string.Join(",", lst);
```

Result:

> OU=Users,OU=Accounts,OU=Employees

I do the same thing to a list called `dcList` that produces the same kind of string:

```
DC = string.Join(",", lst);
```

Result:

> DC=severname,DC=another_value,DC=com

to which I join together with OU to get the complete string, like so:

```
string container = string.Join(",", OU, DC);
```

End result:

> OU=Users,OU=Accounts,OU=Employees,DC=sever,DC=othervalue,DC=com

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the first line of code. Please copy/paste your code exactly as it is, thanks :)

Comment: You should really fix typos in your code. If you want to show us multiple revisions of the same piece of code - you should split those into different code blocks, instead of putting them all together and creating a mess. Otherwise your question might get closed. Notice, that we deal with real code here, which works and compiles, not with pseudo-code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.Join` can work with `IEnumerable<T>` so its not necessary to pass list to it. Same goes for `foreach`: you do not have to call `ToList()` at the end of your first query, you can loop through initial enumeration. 
With LINQ you can join strings like that:

```
//you can call `ToList()` at the end, if you need to cache query results, but you dont have to
var fields = db.sda(sql).Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("txt"));
//you can merge this Select with the previous one, if you are not going to re-use `fields` enumeration
var ou = fields.Select(f => "OU=" + f);
var dc = someOtherFields.Select(f => "DC=" + f);

var result = String.Join(",", ou.Concat(dc));
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [tinstaafl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/33306/tinstaafl)' [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/71057/29371) you can also use the `StringBuilder.Length` property and turn this into a extension method like

```
public static String Join(this IEnumerable<String> list, String category, String delimiter)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (String item in list)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1},", category, item);
    }
    if (list.Any()) { sb.Length -= 1; }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This can be called like

```
String ou = Web.Info.Ldap.ouList.Join("OU", ",");
String dc = Web.Info.Ldap.dcList.Join("DC", ",");
String container = String.Concat(ou, ",", dc);
```

Comment: I find the meaning of this method unclear. IMO, readability and comprehension trump speed.

Answer (score 1):

One simpler way to get the formatted strings is to use a StringBuilder and build the string in the loop instead of creating a separate list and joining it:

```
string MakeFormattedString(List<string> input, string category)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < input.Count - 1; i++ )
    {
        sb.AppendFormat(category + "={0},", input[i]);
    }
    sb.AppendFormat(category + "={0}", input[i]);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then something like this should work:

```
 string OU = MakeFormattedString(Web.Info.Ldap.ouList, "OU");
 string DC = MakeFormattedString(Web.Info.Ldap.dcList, "DC");
 string container = string.Join(",", OU, DC);
```

Comment: Instead of `sb.AppendFormat(category + "={0},", input[i]);` you could simply do `sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1},",category, input[i]);`

Comment: -1: function explodes if called with 0 inputs.